# ASP.NET auto reload div without using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have a winforms(windows) application and it has a form that reloads a datagrid every 30secs, this form has a few other controls in it as well.

I am trying to convert this application to the web(ASP.NET MVC5) and I trying to figure out a way to do the reload portion of my application.

I have the page created and I have a button on the page that reloads the data on the table(partialview is returned). How can I make that partial view auto reload itself? Without using javascript or jquery?

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned a div specifically, but I don't think that's possible. You could however use an iframe, maybe.

You could use a [refresh header](http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-meta-refresh.phtml) on a page embedded in an iframe.

So, we'll call the file that goes in the iframe `refreshing_form.html` and here's its structure:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=refreshing_form.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Your content here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

And then in the main page, we have the iframe...

```
<iframe src="refreshing_form.html"></iframe>
```

The `refreshing_form.html` will reload itself in a loop forever. The containing page with the iframe will *not* reload (though the content of the iframe will). Poor man's ajax.

However, this seems like a lot of cludge to do something that javascript is really good at. Are you sure you can't use it?